# How to disable "save address book" in checkout process?

Tags: magento-1.9

I basically want to disable this section where it asks the logged in user whether "Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address."

I have tried removing the condition in billing.phtml but then it will just appear blank. I need it to take the logged in user to the exact same process as guest users (display the billing form automatically).

Here is the condition in billing.phtml:

```
<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm sure there is more than just removing this block of code...

Comment: Hello Jnsn_ Can you write  same thing for magento 2  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution it will help you...
Go to file "checkout/onepage/billing.phtml" Remove bellow code at **line 30**

```
<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
    <li class="wide">
        <label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and remove if condition at line 38 `<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?> style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>`

Also Remove below code at **Line 173** :

```
<?php if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && $this->customerHasAddresses()):?>
                <li class="control">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Save in address book') ?>" id="billing:save_in_address_book" onchange="if(window.shipping) shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);"<?php if ($this->getAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()):?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="checkbox" /><label for="billing:save_in_address_book"><?php echo $this->__('Save in address book') ?></label>
                </li>
            <?php else:?>
                <li class="no-display"><input type="hidden" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" /></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

**Note** : Must have a backup of billing.phtml before editing.

Comment: PERFECT!!!! I'm sure someone else down the road will want this too